# How to build multimodule project faster in maven 2?

Tags: maven, build

I have a multimodule maven project in which there are 7 several modules.
Every time I modify a code in one of the module and run mvn clean install, it takes some time and I think there might be a way to reduce time of builds since I only change small part of the code and I think it effects only limited area.
So I guess instead of running "mvn clean install" there is a better command option.

I am using maven 2.x.

Any better ideas?

TIA

Comment: Which version ? Maven 2.2.1 or Maven 2.0.X ?

Comment: Why you using "clean install" and not just "install"?  That is possibly the easiest fix.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using 2.2.1

Comment: @wytten the maven script is legacy code and basically I do not touch it until I fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The "clean" goal deletes all the target folders which contain the compiled classes, it should not be necessary to run that goal as part of the modify-compile-test cycle that you may run many times per day. In your case most of the time is probably spent re-compiling all the Java files, due to the class files having been deleted during the "clean" goal. So I would use "mvn install" when testing local changes, and "mvn clean install" only periodically, like when you get other developers changes to integrate with, or when testing immediately before a release.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [following](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html):

```
mvn -pl TheModuleYouHaveChanged -amd install
```

or maybe a

```
mvn -pl TheModuleYouHaveChanged -amd package
```

is enough.